# Using logback in Payara 6 produces ClassNotFoundException

Tags: logback, payara

I want to use logback 1.4.14 inside Payara 6.2024.1. Therefore I created a domain using

```
asadmin create-domain TEST
```

I moved these jars into `${payaraRoot}\glassfish\domains\TEST\lib\ext`:

- `logback-core-1.4.14.jar`
- `logback-classic-1.4.14.jar`

I moved `logback.xml` into `${payaraRoot}\glassfish\domains\TEST\config`.
Furthermore I replaced the handler in `${payaraRoot}\glassfish\domains\TEST\config\logging.properties` with
`handlers=org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler`.

When I start the domain I can see that my logfile is generated in `${payaraRoot}\glassfish\domains\TBCS\logs` according to the `logback.xml`. So I know that logback is picked up. I can also see the normal Payara bootstrap log messages. So it seems that it works.

But accessing the admin gui via locahost:4848 fails and in the log file the following stacktrace is produced:

> 02.02.2024 14:36:38.858  [Thread-14] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext:5770 - Exception during
> cleanup after start failed org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
> Manager has not yet been started  at
> org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:872)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:5951)
> at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.stop(WebModule.java:648)    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5768)
> at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:619)   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startChildren(ContainerBase.java:1549)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1225)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:933)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startChildren(ContainerBase.java:1549)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1225)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:396)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:951)    at
> com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.postConstruct(WebContainer.java:551)
> at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:303)
> at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:351)
> at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:466)
> at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:59)
> at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:47)
> at
> org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:74)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at
> org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:131)
> at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:176)
> at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:98)
> at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2103)
> at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
> at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
> at
> org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineInfo.getContainer(EngineInfo.java:86)
> at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.startContainers(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1333)
> at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.startEngine(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1095)
> at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:990)
> at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepare(ApplicationLifecycle.java:456)
> at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:433)
> at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.load(InstallerThread.java:215)
> at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.run(InstallerThread.java:103)
> 02.02.2024 14:36:38.860  [Thread-14] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase:1552 - Container
> StandardEngine[glassfish-web].StandardHost[server].StandardContext[]
> has not been started org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> jakarta/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5772)
> at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:619)   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startChildren(ContainerBase.java:1549)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1225)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:933)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startChildren(ContainerBase.java:1549)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1225)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:396)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:951)    at
> com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.postConstruct(WebContainer.java:551)
> at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:303)
> at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:351)
> at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:466)
> at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:59)
> at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:47)
> at
> org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:74)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at
> org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:131)
> at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:176)
> at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:98)
> at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2103)
> at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
> at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
> at
> org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineInfo.getContainer(EngineInfo.java:86)
> at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.startContainers(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1333)
> at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.startEngine(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1095)
> at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:990)
> at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepare(ApplicationLifecycle.java:456)
> at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:433)
> at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.load(InstallerThread.java:215)
> at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.run(InstallerThread.java:103)
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> jakarta/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer   at
> java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)   at
> java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)    at
> java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:579)
> at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.APIClassLoaderServiceImpl$APIClassLoader.loadClass(APIClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:281)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:579)
> at
> com.sun.enterprise.loader.CurrentBeforeParentClassLoader.loadClass(CurrentBeforeParentClassLoader.java:83)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
> at
> org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1797)
> at
> org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1696)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)    at
> java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)     at
> java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.nextProviderClass(ServiceLoader.java:1217)
> at
> java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1228)
> at
> java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1273)
> at
> java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1309)
> at
> java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1393)
> at
> org.glassfish.web.loader.ServletContainerInitializerUtil.getInterestList(ServletContainerInitializerUtil.java:191)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.callServletContainerInitializers(StandardContext.java:5819)
> at
> com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.callServletContainerInitializers(WebModule.java:736)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5747)
> ... 30 common frames omitted Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> jakarta.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
> ... 56 common frames omitted
> 02.02.2024 14:36:39.126  [Thread-14] INFO  c.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService:439 - Loading
> application __admingui done in 1.411 ms

Basically it says `ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer`. But when I remove the two logback jars from the lib\ext directory everything works just fine.

What do I have to do to get logback 1.4.14 work in Payara 6.2024.1 (Community Full)? The steps I took work fine for logback 1.4.14 and Payara 5.2022.5 (Community Full).